# View all the registered users

Tags: django, django-admin

I built a login form and I can login as main admin, I wants that when i logged in as admin,all the users which are in auth_user table get listed in admin profile so that i can edit them manually.

So please tell me how can I access that auth_user table so that I can get all users information.

Comment: What did you try? Did you read the documentation on [django.contrib.admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/)?

Comment: You are trying nothing and even not commenting on the answer wheather it is working for you are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a one line sql command

```
SELECT * from  auth_user;
```

else

import your User model like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and try this(Django queryset )

```
User.objects.all()
```

Comment: I used it in view.py file as. **users=User.objects.all()
** and then return `context= {'users':users}
     return render_to_response('profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))` and then used 'users 'in my html file to print data but is not working.

Comment: for use in users: print use first try this line just after User.objects.all() and check what it's returning

Comment: if u dont mind can you give me your mail id so that I can mail you my code and you can track the in better way

Comment: its pring nothing mean you have not added anything in your auth_user table add some value first

Comment: In my auth_user table there are some users, and i already told you that i can login to there accounts as well as to admin account.
may be the thing which you told me i am doing that in wrong way.

Comment: have you imported from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 in your views

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16187/discussion-between-user1614526-and-neeraj)